# How to create an in-house Spark package repository?

Tags: apache-spark

How can I create an in-house repository for Spark packages?  I would like to create an in-house repository that I could use via `spark.jars.repositories`.

Is this just a Web server and some JAR files, or do I need to install some software, configure metadata, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark expects jars in maven-style coordinates. You can choose one of the maven repository managers listed here https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html like Apache Archiva (open source) or JFrog Artifactory Open Source (open source).

If you are happy to upload artifacts manually you can go for a simple webserver with a WebDAv module as shown here https://gist.github.com/EronWright/d856aad6302e0c18ccd96164540a653c.